# exec() on a shared folder, in windows

Tags: php, windows, exec

When I use the PHP exec() command on a mounted shared folder I do not get an output. When I run the same command via the command line it works fine. Example:

My W:\ drive is a shared drive. When I am in CMD.exe and I run this command it works:

```
dir W:\
```

When I run this command in PHP I do not get an output:

```
shell_exec("dir W:\")
```

I don't think its a permissions issue; the user manually running the command on CMD.exe is the same user that PHP is using to run the script. I verified this by running `shell_exec("whoami")`.

Please note, when I run `shell_exec("C:\")` it works fine, its simply not working on shared drives.

Comment: Are you getting any output? As in other than this command? Are you getting a parse error or similar that is not being displayed? Have you checked the error log? Simply stating "it doesn't work" doesn't really help much. On windows php only does an internal call to `cmd /c {your command}` so it would have to run with the same restrictions that cmd implies. Also, are you escaping your slash? Using double quotes you also need to double escape them.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the network share path like `\\shareName\path\`? I'm pretty certain the drive letters are per user and it is likely the user php is running under doesn't have access to your mapping. Edit: You could also run the php script on the command line which would run under your account and likely have access to the drive mapping.

Comment: I am not getting an output at all.

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: When I run the page on the command line it works. So it looks like it would be a permissions issue. But when I run shell_exec(whoami) via the web it returns the same user as the me running it manually.

Comment: Does the share drive exist (e.g. check `net use`)? Normally they're created per login session, i.e. the NT object symlink is created in `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx`, where `xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx` is a login session ID. So even for the same user it may be a different login session that doesn't have the drive defined.